# R code: Merge two data based on the information from one column of one data and one variable name of the other data

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, reshape

I have a huge data set, but to ask my question I create simplified data..

I would like to merge two different database based on the information from one column of one data and a variable name of the other data.

```
  d1 <- data.frame(subject = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),stime=c('4/16/2012','4/17/2012','4/18/2012','4/19/2012','4/20/2012','4/21/2012','4/16/2012','4/17/2012','4/18/2012','4/19/2012','4/20/2012','4/21/2012'))
  d2 <- data.frame(x1 = c(11.5,12.3,22,34,25,35),x2=c(4,16,23,25,33,45),stime=c('4/16/2012','4/17/2012','4/18/2012','4/19/2012','4/20/2012','4/21/2012'))


> d1
   subject     stime
1        1 4/16/2012
2        1 4/17/2012
3        1 4/18/2012
4        1 4/19/2012
5        1 4/20/2012
6        1 4/21/2012
7        2 4/16/2012
8        2 4/17/2012
9        2 4/18/2012
10       2 4/19/2012
11       2 4/20/2012
12       2 4/21/2012

> d2
    x1 x2     stime
1 11.5  4 4/16/2012
2 12.3 16 4/17/2012
3 22.0 23 4/18/2012
4 34.0 25 4/19/2012
5 25.0 33 4/20/2012
6 35.0 45 4/21/2012
```

Basically, I would like to create data like this..
It means that I would like to merge these datas based on variable names of d2 such as x1, x2 and the information from "subject" of d1.
Is it possible? Please help me.. thank you so much!

```
   subject     stime Variable
1        1 4/16/2012  11.5
2        1 4/17/2012  12.3 
3        1 4/18/2012  22.0
4        1 4/19/2012  34.0
5        1 4/20/2012  25.0
6        1 4/21/2012  35.0
7        2 4/16/2012  4
8        2 4/17/2012  16
9        2 4/18/2012  23
10       2 4/19/2012  25
11       2 4/20/2012  33
12       2 4/21/2012  45
```

Comment: merge is what you needed..

Answer (score 4):

All the answers here so far, in one way or other, transforms `d2` into *long form* first and **then** performs a merge. This results in allocating memory for the (intermediate) molten data, and once again for the final `merge/join`. Since you mention *huge data* (but not mention the dimensions), I'm assuming that optimising for both *speed* **and** *memory* would be most desirable.

Here is how:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.4+
setkey(setDT(d2), stime)
setDT(d1)
get_cols = function(d1_subject, d1_time) {
    d2[J(d1_time), list(stime, var = if (d1_subject==1) x1 else x2)]
}
d1[, get_cols(subject, stime), by=subject]
#     subject     stime  var
#  1:       1 4/16/2012 11.5
#  2:       1 4/17/2012 12.3
#  3:       1 4/18/2012 22.0
#  4:       1 4/19/2012 34.0
#  5:       1 4/20/2012 25.0
#  6:       1 4/21/2012 35.0
#  7:       2 4/16/2012  4.0
#  8:       2 4/17/2012 16.0
#  9:       2 4/18/2012 23.0
# 10:       2 4/19/2012 25.0
# 11:       2 4/20/2012 33.0
# 12:       2 4/21/2012 45.0
```

We first convert the data.frames to data.tables using `setDT()` function. Then we *set* `d2`'s key column as `stime`, which *sorts* `d2` by that column in increasing order, and marks that column as *key column*, on which we will join in the next step.

In the next step, we first group `d1` by `subject`, and *for each group*, we call the function `get_cols` which takes `subject` and `stime` values from `d1` corresponding to *that* group. For each group, we perform a *join* on `d2`'s key column `stime` using the value `d1_time` which corresponds to `d1$stime` corresponding to that `subject` and we extract column `x1` or `x2` depending on `subject == 1 or 2`.

Here, the intermediate result from `melt` is never materialised, and is therefore memory efficient and the joins are fast using binary search.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tidyr` and `dplyr`:

*From @docendodiscimus suggestion for a more idiomatic solution*

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

gather(d2, subject, value, x1:x2) %>% 
  mutate(subject = as.numeric(gsub("^x", "", subject))) %>%
  inner_join(., d1)

#Joining by: c("stime", "subject")
#       stime subject value
#1  4/16/2012       1  11.5
#2  4/17/2012       1  12.3
#3  4/18/2012       1  22.0
#4  4/19/2012       1  34.0
#5  4/20/2012       1  25.0
#6  4/21/2012       1  35.0
#7  4/16/2012       2   4.0
#8  4/17/2012       2  16.0
#9  4/18/2012       2  23.0
#10 4/19/2012       2  25.0
#11 4/20/2012       2  33.0
#12 4/21/2012       2  45.0
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is kind of a combination of merge and melt. Really just melting `d2` seems to returns what you want

```
library(reshape2)
melt(d2)
```

of course you get the column "variable" with the subset name combined with "x". But you can transform the other ID's to include an "x" and then merge

```
mm <- merge(transform(d1, variable=paste0("x",subject)), melt(d2))
mm

#        stime variable subject value
# 1  4/16/2012       x1       1  11.5
# 2  4/16/2012       x2       2   4.0
# 3  4/17/2012       x1       1  12.3
# 4  4/17/2012       x2       2  16.0
# 5  4/18/2012       x1       1  22.0
# 6  4/18/2012       x2       2  23.0
# 7  4/19/2012       x1       1  34.0
# 8  4/19/2012       x2       2  25.0
# 9  4/20/2012       x1       1  25.0
# 10 4/20/2012       x2       2  33.0
# 11 4/21/2012       x1       1  35.0
# 12 4/21/2012       x2       2  45.0
```

If you want to resort and drop the extra column you can do

```
subset(mm[order(mm$subject),], select=-variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired result can be achieved by using a combination of `melt` and `merge`.

```
library(reshape)
colnames(d2)<-c("1","2","stime") #change the column names from "x1","x2" to "1","2"
```

We use `melt` on `d2`. The `id` variable `stime`is left unchanged, while a new column `subject` is formed by using the other columns.

```
x2 <- melt(d2,id=c("stime"),variable_name="subject")  
#>x2
#       stime subject value
#1  4/16/2012       1  11.5
#2  4/17/2012       1  12.3
#3  4/18/2012       1  22.0
#4  4/19/2012       1  34.0
#5  4/20/2012       1  25.0
#6  4/21/2012       1  35.0
#7  4/16/2012       2   4.0
#8  4/17/2012       2  16.0
#9  4/18/2012       2  23.0
#10 4/19/2012       2  25.0
#11 4/20/2012       2  33.0
#12 4/21/2012       2  45.0
```

We can now `merge` `d1` and `x2` by common variables `subject` and `stime` to get the desired result.

```
dd2 <- merge(d1, x2, by=c("subject","stime"))        
#> dd2
#   subject     stime value
#1        1 4/16/2012  11.5
#2        1 4/17/2012  12.3
#3        1 4/18/2012  22.0
#4        1 4/19/2012  34.0
#5        1 4/20/2012  25.0
#6        1 4/21/2012  35.0
#7        2 4/16/2012   4.0
#8        2 4/17/2012  16.0
#9        2 4/18/2012  23.0
#10       2 4/19/2012  25.0
#11       2 4/20/2012  33.0
#12       2 4/21/2012  45.0
```